# After updating to PHP 8, setting custom HTTP Cache Headers with API platform is not working anymore

Tags: php, symfony, caching, varnish, api-platform.com

I use Varnish for my API platform endpoints in a symfony app. API platform version is 2.6 and since I made an upgrade to PHP 8, cache_headers option from API platform config is not working anymore.

I have this configuration for a specific api platform endpoint

```
collectionOperations:
    voucher_list:
        method: GET
        cache_headers:
            max_age: 3600
            shared_max_age: 3600
        path: /account/{account_id}/vouchers
        requirements:
            account_id: '\d+'
        normalization_context:
            groups: ['voucher_list:read']
```

This worked perfectly with php 7.4.

Now, Cache-Control has the value no-cache on this endpoint.

Cache-Control will be set only if I set the default configuration in api_platform.yaml

```
http_cache:
    max_age: 3600
    shared_max_age: 3600
    vary: ['Accept']
    public: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your collection operations `cache_headers`, max age is defined as `max-age` instead of `max_age`

As i see in this documentation https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/#setting-custom-http-cache-headers

`max_age` seems the correct param name.
As you can see in your generic configuration, you correctly set `max_age` for `http_cache`

Even in api platform 2.6 https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.6/core/performance/#setting-custom-http-cache-headers

Comment: You are correct but this was a typo when I wrote the question. In my code I have the correct form max_age. I edited now the question. With the correct param name is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed with update to latest version of api platform